# How to solve this integral equation involving CDF of a random variable?

Tags: nonlinear-system

Suppose $F_X(x)$ is CDF of random variable $X$. I am going to find the value of $x$ such that the following equation is satisfied:
$$
ax+bxF_X(x)+ c \int_{x}^{\infty} \left[  1-F_X(y) \right] \text{d}y = 0
$$

where $a,b,c$ are known parameters.

Is there any way to solve this equation?

Comment: Newton-Raphson.

Comment: Is it possible to have a simpler expression analytically?

Comment: Unlikely. When you set $c=0$ and take as $F_X$ the CDF of the exponential distribution we already have a problem that calls in the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: What is $c$ is not equal to 0 and parameters are set such that we are sure that there exists a solution to this equation?

Comment: See my first comment. That method is dead simple to implement, say, in python. Existence of a solution and finding it in closed form are two different things. You should also work a bit yourself and not assume that others know all the answers to every question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be true for all $x$, you'll have to solve for $F_X(x)$.

We'll start by differentiating both sides wrt $x$:
$$a+bF_X(x)+bx\frac{\text d F_X(x)}{\text dx}-c(1-F_X(x))=0.$$
Rearranging,
$$bx\frac{\text dF_X(x)}{\text d x}+(b+c)F_X(x)+a-c=0.$$
So we got ourselves a differential equation in $F_X(x)$ which can be solved via power series and Frobenius method.

Supposing $F_X(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$, we'd get
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}[b(n+1)+c]a_nx^n=c-a$$
Therefore, for $n=0$ you can find $a_0\neq 0$ and for $n\geq 1$ you'll find that $a_n=0$ so we'll use Frobenius:
$$n=0: a_0=\frac{c-a}{b+c}$$
$$n\geq 1: F_X(x)\sim x^r\implies [b(r+1)+c]x^r=0\implies r=-\frac{b+c}{b}$$
Finally, combining both we'd get that the equation holds true $\forall x$ if
$$F_X(x)=\frac{c-a}{b+c}+Cx^{-\frac{b+c}{b}}$$

Comment: Nice. But OP wants $F_X$ to be given and solve for that $x$ in the question.

Comment: Oops, I'll remove

Comment: I'd probably wait a bit. One never knows.:)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I assume that CDF is given and I should find the value of $x$. I was wondering if it is possible to use Laplace transform. I tried but I could not find any answer.